# Reinstall a module that has .yml file in config\install

Tags: configuration, installation

A good enhancement in Drupal 8 is having list of yml file to import via installation in mymodule_root\config\install, but this means I can not reinstall a module because the configuration settings already exist in the active configuration.

Actually the problem is when uninstalling the module: The imported configuration settings, imported during installation, aren't waived.

> [image: screenshot]

#### Test scenario

Put this sample .yml file in yourmodule_root\config\install\systme.site.yml.

```
name: 'Admissions at Adelaide'
mail: admin22@example.com
slogan: ''
page:
  403: ''
  404: ''
  front: caslogin
admin_compact_mode: false
weight_select_max: 100
langcode: en
default_langcode: en
```

Comment: I deleted the values in config table directly.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to remove mymodule configurations on uninstall](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/173684/2089) for a best-practice solution.

Basically, you can enforce the dependency on your module in your configuration files.  So when the module is uninstalled, it's associated configuration will be uninstalled as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's **not** best practice, but you may try to add a yourmodule.install file and add something like this:

```
function yourmodule_migrate_uninstall() {

  // Delete Configuration generated at at activation.
  $dir = DRUPAL_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodule') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config/install';
  $files = file_scan_directory($dir, '/.*\.yml$/');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    db_delete('config')
      ->condition('name', $file->name)
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

Better answers's are welcome ;)